# Sum of real numbers and modular arithmetic

Tags: summation, modular-arithmetic

Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\exists i \in \{1,...,m\}: \lambda_i \neq 0$.

Given the sum:
$$ S = \sum_{i,j \in \{1,...,m\}, i \neq j} \lambda_i \lambda_j z_{ij} $$

We know that $z_{ij} = 0(\mod 2)$.
Can I say that $S = 0 (\mod 2)$?
I am confused by real numbers in the sum.

Comment: Your sum can be anything, including even, odd, or non-integer.

Answer (score 0):

No. You can show this by a counter example:

Define $ z := 2^{i + j} $ and $ m := 3 $. Now, $ \lambda = \{0.1,\ 0.3,\ 0.4\} $. Try to compute $ S $ now.